# I have a second hard drive installed in my hardware which I can't access from Debian (not mounted)

Tags: debian, mount, hard-disk, fdisk, volume

I just installed Debian but I had some problem during the installation.
I first installed my OS on HDD  cause I wanted a dualboot with Windows (which WAS located on the SSD) but I couldn't complete it so I decided to say goodbye to Windows and install Debian it again on SSD.

Now in my desktop I can see both hard drives but I can't mount the HDD.

I'll paste some relevant information:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sdb: 89.4 GiB, 96029466624 bytes, 187557552 sectors
Disk model: KINGSTON RBU-SNS
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x34f08e2e

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *         2048 185556991 185554944 88.5G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2       185559038 187555839   1996802  975M  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       185559040 187555839   1996800  975M 82 Linux swap / Solaris


Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: ST1000LM024 HN-M
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x55786839

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1             2048 1951522815 1951520768 930.6G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1951524862 1953523711    1998850   976M  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1951524864 1953523711    1998848   976M 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

The drive I'm trying to access is /dev/sda

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            5.8G     0  5.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.2G  9.4M  1.2G   1% /run
/dev/sdb1        87G  5.4G   77G   7% /
tmpfs           5.9G   60M  5.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           1.2G   20K  1.2G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Here's what I tried:

```
~$ sudo fsck.ext4 -f /dev/sda
e2fsck 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext4: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext4: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

Found a dos partition table in /dev/sda

~$ sudo resize2fs /dev/sda 8193
resize2fs 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.

~$ sudo resize2fs /dev/sda 32768
resize2fs 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

inside mount output I fount the other drive infos:

```
/dev/sdb1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
```

So I wrote:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /
```

And the hard disk icon on my desktop disappeared. After a reboot everything's back as it was, I can see the icon, I can't access the driver.
If I click on the Icon:

**Failed to mount "999 GB Volume"**
**Not authorized to perform operation**

*Please help*

Comment: I think you should not mount the hard drive to `/`. You should make a directory in your directory structure and mount a hard drive there. Like this: `sudo mkdir /hdd; sudo mount /dev/sda1 /hdd`. You will have the contents of your hard drive in `/hdd` folder then. Read this: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/linux-filesystem-windows.

Comment: If you have a bad superblock you might need to restore the superblock from a different inode.  This explains how to do that:  https://linuxexpresso.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/repair-a-broken-ext4-superblock-in-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

Since you just installed Debian and have no important data on this computer, I guess you can experience and afford to make mistakes. You don't understand filesystems and mounting at all, and this is your chance to learn about it.

First, `/dev/sda` is **partitioned**. According to your `fdisk` output, the partitions are

```
/dev/sda1             2048 1951522815 1951520768 930.6G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1951524862 1953523711    1998850   976M  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1951524864 1953523711    1998848   976M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

I guess that `/dev/sda1` has already been formatted as a filesystem. To be certain, and if there is nothing worth keeping on that disk, you can **create a filesystem** yourself:

```
mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sda1
```

If `/dev/sda1` contains a filesystem already, the command will complain, since it doesn't want overwrite potentially important data. You can force `mkfs` to overwrite data, but I'd say to leave it if you get complaints.

Next, to use the filesystem, you must **mount** it. Mounting means integrating a separate filesystem in your existing filesystem tree. To do that, you need a so-called *mount point*. You create a directory, for example `/mnt/data`, which will be your mount point. It should be empty, since mounting a filesystem will hide (though not remove) all files and directories that exist in the mount point. Therefore, try this:

```
mkdir /mnt/data
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/data
```

Now it's mounted, and the `df` command will list it. You can `cd /mnt/data` and create files and directories. Whatever you create under `/mnt/data` will reside on `/dev/sda1` (as long as it's mounted).

Comment: ~$ sudo mksf -t ext4 /dev/sda1 -->
sudo: mksf: command not found |||
I installed xfsprogs packets but I still cant run the command, what should I install more to run it?

Comment: No need to install anything. Just find the typo. By the way, xfsprog is for XFS filesystems, not ext4.

Comment: Your method mounted the hard-disk at first but I can't see the disk on the desktop anymore after that. Futhermore after a reboot every change went discarded and I see the disk again "not mounted" on the desktop

Comment: If you mount at /mnt/data or /hdd you have to start & / & look for the folders. It will not be shown automatically in file browser. You can also mount into /home, if desired but must unmount any other mount first.  You may also have to give yourself ownership & permissions. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Comment: I can't comment on the desktop. However, it is true that a manual mount will be forgotten at reboot. One method of making a mount persistent is putting it into the /etc/fstab file. I don't know if your desktop has ways to do that, or perhaps it may use other methods to achieve persistence.